Integrate gives inconsistent result for gamma-like integral with complex variables
I am trying to come up with a generic formula for the below integral, which is analogous to the upper incomplete gamma function,
Clear[x, t, n]; x1 =  FullSimplify[Integrate[(1 + I t)^(-1 - I x) E^(2 \[Pi] I n t) , {t, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> x > 0 && n > 0]]

I used assumptions to increase the likelihood of getting a correct answer. It gives me the not so neat function below:

But I usually don't blindly trust Mathematica's results, so I tried to validate the formula it gave me,
Clear[t]; x = 2; n = 1; N[{x1 = Integrate[(1 + I t)^(-1 - I x) E^(2 \[Pi] I n t) , {t, 0, 1}],  x2 = I 2^((I x)/2) E^(-2 n \[Pi] - (13 \[Pi] x)/4) ((1 - I) n)^(I x) \[Pi]^(I x) ((1 - E^(2 \[Pi] x)) Gamma[-I x] - Gamma[-I x, -2 n \[Pi]] + E^(4 \[Pi] x) Gamma[-I x, (-2 - 2 I) n \[Pi]])}, 5]

but the values don't match:

This seems to be widespread in my version of Mathematica (13.0.1.0, windows 10 x64), I just found out nothing seems to work.
c = 1; b = 1; x = 1; n = 2; N[{Integrate[E^(2 \[Pi] I t n) HypergeometricU[c + I x, 1 + c + I x, 2 \[Pi] (1 + I t)] , {t, 0, 1}], E^(-2 n \[Pi]) (2 \[Pi])^(-c - I x) (-I ExpIntegralE[c + I x, -2 n \[Pi]] - 2 (1 + I)^(-1 - c - I x) ExpIntegralE[c + I x, (-2 - 2 I) n \Pi]])}, 5]

Below a quick view of the new formula:

Any ideas? I'm getting a little desperate with so many bugs that I'm not sure what's going on.

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

x1[n_, x_] = Assuming[x > 0 && n > 0, Integrate[
    (1 + I  t)^(-1 - I  x)  E^(2  π  I  n  t), {t, 0, 1}] //
   Simplify]

(* -I E^(-π (2 n + x)) n^(I x) (2 π)^(
 I x) ((-1 + E^(2 π x)) Gamma[-I x] + Gamma[-I x, -2 n π] - 
   E^(2 π x) Gamma[-I x, (-2 - 2 I) n π]) *)

x2[n_?Positive, x_?Positive] := Integrate[
   (1 + I  t)^(-1 - I  x)  E^(2  π  I  n  t), {t, 0, 1}] //
  FullSimplify

x3[n_?Positive, x_?Positive] := NIntegrate[
  (1 + I  t)^(-1 - I  x)  E^(2  π  I  n  t), {t, 0, 1},
  WorkingPrecision -> 20,
  MinRecursion -> 5,
  MaxRecursion -> 20]

{x1[1, 2], x2[1, 2], x3[1, 2]} // N

(* {-0.872307 + 0.00711754 I, -0.662633 + 0.0372631 I, -0.872307 + 0.00711754 I} *)

x1 is consistent with numerical integration, i.e., x3
And @@ Flatten[
  Outer[x1[#1, #2] == x3[#1, #2] &, Range[1/4, 5, 1/4], Range[1/4, 5, 1/4]]]

(* True *)

EDIT: As requested in a comment, replacing(1 + I t)^(-1 - I x) with (1 + I  t)^(-c - I  x) and c > 0
x4[n_, x_, c_] = Assuming[x > 0 && n > 0 && c > 0,
  Integrate[
    (1 + I  t)^(-c - I  x)  E^(2 π I n t), {t, 0, 1}] //
   FullSimplify]

(* -I E^(π (-I c - 2 n - x)) n^(-1 + c + I x) (2 π)^(-1 + c + 
  I x) ((E^(2 I c π) - E^(2 π x)) Gamma[1 - c - I x] - 
   E^(2 I c π) Gamma[1 - c - I x, -2 n π] + 
   E^(2 π x) Gamma[1 - c - I x, (-2 - 2 I) n π]) *)

x4 reduces to x1 for c == 1
x1[n, x] == x4[n, x, 1] // Simplify

(* True *)

EDIT 2: For the revised question,
x5[n_, x_, c_] = Assuming[c > 0 && n > 0 && x > 0,
  Integrate[
    E^(2  π  I  t  n)  HypergeometricU[c + I  x, 1 + c + I  x, 
      2  π  (1 + I  t)], {t, 0, 1}] // Simplify]

(* -(1/(2 π))
 I E^(π (-I c - 2 n - x))
   n^(-1 + c + 
   I x) ((E^(2 I c π) - E^(2 π x)) Gamma[1 - c - I x] - 
    E^(2 I c π) Gamma[1 - c - I x, -2 n π] + 
    E^(2 π x) Gamma[1 - c - I x, (-2 - 2 I) n π]) *)

x6[n_?Positive, x_?Positive, c_?Positive] := 
 NIntegrate[
  E^(2  π  I  t  n)  HypergeometricU[c + I  x, 1 + c + I  x, 
    2  π  (1 + I  t)], {t, 0, 1}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 20, 
  MinRecursion -> 5, 
  MaxRecursion -> 20]

{x5[n, x, c], x6[n, x, c]} /. {c -> 1.0`25, x -> 1.0`25, n -> 2.0`25} // N

(* {0.0100435 + 0.0187961 I, 0.0100435 + 0.0187961 I} *)


Thanks a lot, let me try it. Btw Are you able to come up with a generic closed formula as a function of any known functions?

Oh, looks like it's the expression in the brackets. Awesome.

With your version but on a Mac
$Version

(* "13.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

x5[n_, x_, c_] = Assuming[c > 0 && n > 0 && x > 0,
  Integrate[
    E^(2 π I t n) HypergeometricU[c + I x, 1 + c + I x, 
      2 π (1 + I t)], {t, 0, 1}] // Simplify]

(* -(1/(2 π))
 I E^(π (-I c - 2 n - x))
   n^(-1 + c + 
   I x) ((E^(2 I c π) - E^(2 π x)) Gamma[1 - c - I x] - 
    E^(2 I c π) Gamma[1 - c - I x, -2 n π] + 
    E^(2 π x) Gamma[1 - c - I x, (-2 - 2 I) n π]) *)

x6[n_?Positive, x_?Positive, c_?Positive] := 
 NIntegrate[
  E^(2 π I t n) HypergeometricU[c + I x, 1 + c + I x, 
    2 π (1 + I t)], {t, 0, 1},
  WorkingPrecision -> 20,
  MinRecursion -> 5,
  MaxRecursion -> 20]

{x5[n, x, c], x6[n, x, c]} /. 
  {c -> 1.0`25, x -> 1.0`25, n -> 2.0`25} // N

(* {0.0100435 + 0.0187961 I, 0.0100435 + 0.0187961 I} *)

Also, note that your integrand simplifies
Assuming[c > 0 && n > 0 && x > 0,
 integrand = 
  E^(2 π I t n) HypergeometricU[c + I x, 1 + c + I x, 2 π (1 + I t)] //
    Simplify]

(* E^(2 I n π t) (2 π)^(-c - I x) (1 + I t)^(-c - I x) *)


I hadn't noticed that that function could be simplified to the first form. In that case it doesn't matter, the 2nd form won't be any different.

The purpose of this forum is not to remotely execute code for others. To do that, use the Wolfram Cloud.

Ok, thanks for what you've done so far anyway. I need to find out what's wrong with my installation.

I've tried your tip and was amazed to see my Windows answer is different from the cloud. Great tip, thanks. I didn't know that I could use that and for free. The validation now works.
